# Sorting an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to update a TextArea with information that I submit from an generics arraylist.  As of now the program creates a new Order:

```
Order d1 = new Order();
```

Then the user selects some data and pushes an add button, and the order is added to a TextArea.  The problem I have is that I have to add the order to the correct spot in the list and update it each time. I"m only sorting it by one item.  I'm not really sure how to do that using the CompareTo method.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
 {
     ArrayList<Drink> DrinkArray = new ArrayList<Drink>();

     if (event.getSource() == addcoffeeButton)
     {

         String coffeesize = (String) sizecoffeelist.getSelectedItem();
         double coffeeprice = Double.parseDouble(pricecoffeeTextfield.getText());

         String coffeetype = (String) cuptypecoffeelist.getSelectedItem();
         String coffeecaffeine = (String) caffeineList.getSelectedItem();
         String coffeeroom = (String) roomforcreamList.getSelectedItem();
         String coffeeadditional = additionalflavorList.getText();
         if  ((coffeeadditional.isEmpty()))
             coffeeadditional = "No Additional Flavor";

         Drink d1 = new Coffee(coffeesize, coffeeprice, coffeetype, coffeecaffeine, coffeeroom, coffeeadditional);


          DrinkArray.add(d1);
          orderTextArea.append(d1);
```

So I would have to add the drink to the correct spot before adding it to the array and printing to the text area, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate? You haven't explained very much... what is the *correct* spot? How are you updating it "each time"?

Comment: A small observation, typically orders are handled in FIFO. So the concept of sorting is strange for this case, until customer is not a VIP or something. Beside that you should try to create this more Object Oriented. First replace the strings with enum, string should represent sequence of characters not business logic of app. After that you should have factory that produce the coffee object, then all those settings would not be necessary if some order ordinary B or WNS (White No Sugar) ;-). I advise you to read this book " Head First Design Patterns ".

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that `Drink` implements `Comparable`.  Look at the javadocs if you don't know what that means.

If that's true, you can do this:

```
List<Drink> drinks = new ArrayList<Drink>();
// add Drinks
Collections.sort(drinks); // now they're sorted according to your Comparable.
```

You can also instantiate a `Comparator` and pass it to the sorts method.

Something like this (make the getValue() function whatever you want):

```
public class DrinkComparator implements Comparator<Drink> {
    public int compare(Drink d1, Drink d2) {
       if (d1.getValue() < d2.getValue()) { 
           return -1;
       } else if (d1.getValue() > d2.getValue()) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return 0;
       }
    } 

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.compare(this, (Drink)obj) == 0;
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have it implementing Comparable, but I haven't overrided the CompareTo method yet, how would I go about that if an attribute is length?

Comment: A Drink has a length?  I would have guessed you'd sort them alphabetically by name, or alcohol content, or some other attribute intrinsic to a Drink.  What does length have to do with anything?

Comment: I'm just making a variable up, lets use Size as an example.  I know that I would have to create a new CompareTo method that would compare all the sizes in the array and place them in a specific order, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: That makes no sense, either.  Little about your comments is making sense to me.  Find a tutorial to see how to write a Comparator.  Or shall I spoon feed you?

Comment: I've been searching for about 2 hours now, and this is what I have:  public class DrinkComparator implements Comparator<Drink> {
     public int compare(Drink a, Drink b) {
         int PriceComparison = a.Price.compareTo(b.Price);
         return PriceComparison == 0 ? a.Size.compareTo(b.Size) : PriceComparison;
     }
 }

Comment: I wrote one for you.  Adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to pre-determine the insertion point where the "object" would be inserted...

Take a look at [`Collections.binarySearch(List<T>, T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)

From the Java Docs

> Returns:
>
> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list;
>   **otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)**. The insertion point is defined as
>   the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index
>   of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all
>   elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this
>   guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key
>   is found.